# German equivalent of 'sounding like'

Tags: phrase, phrase-request

To express how something looks like or seems like, in German we can use "aussehen". But In English, depending on the situation, one needs to use 'sounding like' when the object in question is not visible, and only is described verbally. Does this distinction even exist in German? If so, what it the phrase/verb?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the "smells like" question has also been closed.

Comment: I suppose it should, actually. This question actually inspired me to make my own question (I wrote that other, now closed question)

Comment: @SkeletonBow: why close? Phrase requests usually are well received but some users apparently don't like them. Also read http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/1093/what-is-a-phrase-request-and-when-do-we-accept-it-as-on-topic

Comment: Okay, that's interesting. But I realized that my question (and this one, too) are both easily answerable by a dictionary, so it's not completely "on-topic," is it? Though it does seem to generate quite some traffic it seems

Comment: @SkeletonBow: dict.cc is one of the best dictionaries for German online. using the key terms "sound like", and NOT KNOWING THE GERMAN EQUIVALENT ALREADY, can you point out how exactly one is supposed to find it there? If you do, the least is I'll have learned a better lookup method.

Comment: Hmm, that's right. It doesn't look as straightforward as it might seem with "sounds like"!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Take your pick:

> - Es hört sich nach X an.
> - Es hört sich wie X an.
> - Es klingt nach X.
> - Es klingt wie X.

All of them mean "It sounds like X" (and I don't see a difference between them). Please note that the *"sich"* in the first two examples is *not* optional.

Depending on the situation you can also use *"das*" instead of *"es"* (to emphasize). Consider this example:

> A: "I recently bumped into a Radio Shack's display window with my car."
>   B: "Uhh, that sounds expensive." – "Oh, **das** klingt teuer!"

Answer (score 1):

You could express this with the phrase

> Es hört sich nach etwas an